# Function $F$ is surjective if and only if $F$ is $1-1$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

While I was working on proofs of functions, the following claim occurred to me that I think it is correct but I could not prove it. Please note that the claim may not be correct since it is just my hypothesis. So my hypothesis is:

> Let $A$ be a finite set and $F$, a function $F:A\rightarrow A$.
>   $F$ is surjective if and only if $F$ is injective.

Here is how I tried to prove it:

- $\rightarrow$ Let $X$, $Y$, $Z$ and assume $F(X)=F(Y)$. We need to show that $X=Y$ to prove that $F$ is $1-1$. $F(X)$ and $F(Y)\in A$ and $F$ is surjective then $\text{Img}(F)=A$. $A$ is a finite set then $\text{Img}(F)$ is a finite set.

how can I continue the proof?

- $\leftarrow$ We need to show that $A=\text{Img}(F)$ to show that $F$ is surjective but we know that $\text{Img}(F)\subseteq A$ so we need to show $A\subseteq \text{Img}(F)$. Let $x\in A$. We need to show $x\in\text{Img}(F)$.
  $A=\text{Dom}(F)$ and $x\in\text{Dom}(F)$ and $F$ is function so there exists $y$ such that $F(x)=y$.

And here also I got stuck. Any ideas how to continue the proof if it is right..
I know that I did not use that $A$ is a finite set and $F$ is injective in one way because I do not see where I can use in my proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, one has the following

> **Proposition:** If $A$ and $B$ are two finite sets with the same number of elements, and $f:A\to B$, then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. $f$ is injective
> 2. $f$ is surjective
> 3. $f$ is bijective

To prove this, we need the following

> **Lemma:** Let $f:A\to B$ be a function. Then
>
> a) If $f$ is injective and $B$ is finite, then $A$ is also finite and $|A|\le|B|$
>
> b) If $f$ is surjective and $A$ is finite, then $B$ is finite and $|B|\le|A|$

**Proof of the Lemma:**

**a)** Since $f:A\to B$ is injective, $f:A\to \text{im}(f)$ is bijective, and its image set $\text{im}(f)$ is a subset of the finite set $B$, therefore it is finite, and $|A|=|\text{im}(f)|\le|B|$

**b)** Let $n=|A|$ and let $g:A\to n$ be a bijective function. We would like to define an injective function from $B$ to $n$ and apply **a)** . Since $f:A\to B$ is surjective, for each $b\in B$ there is at leat one $a\in A$ so that $f(a)=b$, and although there might be more than one element $a$ in $A$ like that, the images via $g$ of those $a$ are natural numbers less than $n$, so we can choose the smallest of them, that is we choose $k$ the smallest natural number from those natural numbers $i$ that verify $i<n$ and $g(a)=i$. We define the function $h:B\to n$ like:

$$h(b)=\text{the smallest}\;k<n\;\text{such that}\;f(g^{-1}(k))=b$$

The function $h$ is injective: if $b,b'\in B$ are so that $h(b)=h(b')=k$, then $b=f(g^{-1}(k))=b'$. From **a)** , for the injective function $h:B\to n$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ - thus $n$ is finite - we can conclude that $B$ is finite and $|B|\le n=A$

**Proof of he proposition**

$a)\implies b)$: Suppose that $f:A\to B$ is injective, but not surjective: $\text{im}(f)\subset B$. Let $b\in B\text{\im}(f)$. Then $f:A\to B \text{ \ }\{b\}$ and $B \text{ \ }\{b\}$ is a subset of the finite set $B$, so it is a finite set and from **a)** of the previous lemma, $|B|=|A|\le |B \text{ \ }\{b\}|<|B|$, which is a contradiction.

$b)\implies c)$: We only have to prove that $f$ is injective. Suppose that $f$ is surjective but not injective. Then there exist $a,a'\in A$ so that $a\not=a'$ and $f(a)=f(a')$. The restriction $f\restriction (A \text{ \ }\{a\}):A\to B$ is also surjective. From **b)** of the previous lemma, $|B|\le |A \text{ \ }\{a\}|<|A|=|B|$, which is a contradiction.

$c)\implies a)$ There is nothing to prove.

Comment: @Eleonore Saint James In what sense redundant? my proof is perfectly fine, and I think yours is also correct.

Comment: @Akerbeltz.Your proof is too advanced for me. Since I cannot grasp the details, I was wandering whether the idea of a equivalence relation and partition was also used in your proof, which would have made mine redundant.

Comment: No, that was not actually used in my proof. If you don't understand a certain step, you are free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I use the idea of a partition of the domain of F ( that is, of the set A) in classes of elements having the same image. I call P this partition. I want to show that the **cardinal of this partition defines a maximum for the cardinal of the codomain of F**. And without injectivity, this maximum is necessarily less than the cardinal of A. Which makes surjectivity impossible.

---

Rk. I use Card(S) to denote : the cardinal number of the set S.

**First part : If F is surjective, then F is 1-1.**

What is to be proved is equivalent ( by contraposition) to :

**if F is not 1-1, then F is not surjective.**

(1) since F is a function from A to A, F is surjective iff Card ( Codomain) = Card (A).

(2) Define an equivalence relation on the set A by the following formula  : the element x has same image under F as the element y

This equivalence relation partitions A into a collection of sets. Call  **P** this collection . Card(P) is the number of classes of A-elements ( pre-images) such that all elements in each class  have the same image ( under F) .

(3) Card (P) = Card A iff  F is injective ( it means that injectivity guarantees that there is one and only one element in each cell of the partition).

But **if F in not injective ( not 1-1) , Card(P) is less than Card A ( there is at least a cell of the partition that contains 2 elements  of the domain, that is, 2 elements of A)**

(4) Now Card ( Codomain) is, in any case, at most as great as Card (P) ( the number of images under F cannot be greater that the number of classes of preimages having the same image).

So we have :

- By (4) Card (Codomain) is less or equal than Card (P)
- By (3) If F is not injective Card (P) is less than Card(A)
- Therefore : if F is not injective, Card ( Codomain) is less than Card(A)
- But , by (1) if Card ( Codomain) is not equal to Card (A) then F is not surjective.
- Therefore, if F is not injective, F is not surjective.
- Therefore ( by contraposition) if F is surjective, F is injective.

**Second part of the prooF: If F is 1-1, then F is surjective.**

(1) we said earlier that Card(P ) is a maximum for Card ( Codomain). We can add that it is also a minimum. Suppose that the number of images is less that the number of cells of equivalent preimages. That would imply that there is at least an image corresponding to 2 different cells. But this leads to a contradiction : if 2 cells are diffferent, their elements cannot have the same image under F ( being given that cells are determined by the equuivalence relation " having the same image under f)

(2) Since **we have both Card (Codomain) is at most as great as Card(P) and Card( Codomain) is at least as great as P, we must conclude that**

```
                 Cardinal(Codomain)=Card (P)
```

(3) But, if ( by hypothesis) F is 1-1, it means that **card (P) = card (A)** 
( as we said in part 1 of the proof).

(3) So Card (Codomain) = Card (A)

(4) Since F is from A to A, the codomain is a subset of A. Since the only subset of A having the same cardinal as A is A itself, we have

```
                              Codomain of F = A
```

which means that F  ( from A to A) is surjective.

(5) Conclusion : **If F (from A to A)  is injective, then it is also surjective.**